# MultiDataTrigger Not respecting all conditions

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an "On" "Off" switch that I've created and I cannot get the `MultiDataTrigger` to respect all Conditions.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource NoDevExpressStyle}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
               <Border Height="30" Width="81" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
                  <Border.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Style.Triggers>

                           <!-- On Not Selected -->
                           <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{ Binding Path=State}" Value="{x:Static models:ExperimentState.On}" />
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding SwitchClicked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="False"></Condition>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OnInactiveColorBrush}"></Setter>
                           </MultiDataTrigger>

                           <!-- On Selected -->
                           <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{ Binding Path=State}" Value="{x:Static models:ExperimentState.On}" />
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding SwitchClicked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True"></Condition>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OnColorBrush}"></Setter>

                           </MultiDataTrigger>

                           <!-- OFF Not Selected -->
                           <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{ Binding Path=State}" Value="{x:Static models:ExperimentState.Off}" />
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SwitchClicked}" Value="False"></Condition>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OffInactiveColorBrush}"></Setter>
                           </MultiDataTrigger>

                           <!-- Off and selected -->
                           <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{ Binding Path=State}" Value="{x:Static models:ExperimentState.Off}" />
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SwitchClicked}" Value="True"></Condition>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OffColorBrush}"></Setter>
                           </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                     </Style>
                  </Border.Style>
               </Border>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
                  </Trigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button x:Name="Button" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
```

It seems to respecting the "State" Property which is a dependency property that is set once and never changed. However the `SwitchClicked` is not respecting which is a property inside the control.

```
private bool _switchClicked;
public bool SwitchClicked
{
   get => _switchClicked;
   set => _switchClicked = value;
}


private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (Button.Command != null)
   {
      if (Button.Command.CanExecute(Button.CommandParameter))
      {
         SwitchClicked = !SwitchClicked;
         SetValue(IsActiveProperty, !IsActive);
         Button.Command.Execute(null);
      }
   }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to insure that all of my conditions are met?

I have tried binding with relitive source to self and user control, however the SwitchClicked property is in the codebehind and there is no ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) either in your view model (or I suppose your code-behind), otherwise setting your property will not notify
being changed and the binding in your trigger will not update.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

```
public bool SwitchClicked
{
   get => _switchClicked;
   set
   {
      if (_switchClicked != value)
      {
         _switchClicked = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SwitchClicked));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That was the issue, I cannot believe I didn't see that! thank you again!